# Mongodb doesn't show data

Tags: mongodb, pug

I've created a poject using yeoman and created a data base using mongodb, I have a collection called "Datos", I want to see the elements of my database on the screen, this is my code:

```js
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
datos = mongoose.model('Datos');
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use('/',router);
};
router.get('/BaseDatos',function(req,res,next){
    db.getCollection('Datos').find(function(err,Datos){
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.render('index',{
            titulo:'prueba',
            Datos: Datos
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using jade to show the data:

```
extends layout
block content
h2 Sala #{Datos.Nombre}
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Can you help me please?

Comment: the question is a bit unspecific. One advice is to use logging to trace how the data flows through the program, and where it is lost.

Comment: Check that the data exists live and well in the database itself using `mongo`. If the data is there, it's most likely a connection issue. Make sure you're connecting to same port as your `mongod` instance.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to access Datos.Nombre where Nombre is unknown property for collection Datos. 1. add nodejs inspect method in callback where you have Datos collection and show it in logs for expressjs(you probably need to enable logging for express). 2. in case if you don't see data in the console you should check the database. 3. in case if you see the data you should check the template. 4. in the template you will have collection Datos it means you should use iterator to render it

Comment: If you're using Mongoose for your Object Data Model in Mongo DB, you Shoul add Schema in the model of your 'datos. for example please copy it to your text editor module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', new Schema({ 
 uidUser : String,
 question : String,
 gcmID : String,
}));

Answer (score 0):

The result of calling [`find`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) is a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html), not the document results.  Call [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray) on the cursor to get the documents:

```js
db.getCollection('Datos').find().toArray(function(err,Datos){
```